# How to modelEvents work in Marionette.CompositeView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I started to learn `Marionette.View` concept.for this I created model with 1 attribute and assign default value.

I have dropdown list in my html file. Whenever it changes it triggers a function name as `myfunction`.Inside `myFunction` I changed model attribute value.

Whenever attribute value changes automatically it triggers another function.that event I written inside `Marionette.CompositeView`.but it's not working.

Earlier I did same thing using `myModel.on` there it's working fine.But it's not working `modelEvents` in `Marionette.CompositeView`.

let's check the following code.

```
var mymodel=Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults:{
    "name":"oldValue"
}
});
var mymodelObj=new mymodel();
//marionette.View code
var backView=Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
events:{
    "change #pop1":"myFunction"
},
myFunction:function(){
    mymodelObj.set({name:"updatedValue"})
},
modelEvents:{
    "change:name":"myFunction1"
},
myFunction1:function(){
    alert("Hi");
}
 });
//creating instance
var backViewObj=new backView({el:$("#sidebar")});
```

How can I fix this.

Right Now I am trying to understanding where `Marionette.js` useful in my Backbone Applications.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, model is not attached to the view you have created. For modelEvents to be triggered, there should be a model attribute in CompositeView. For this you should specify the model during initialization of CompositeView;

```
var backViewObj=new backView({el:$("#sidebar"), model : mymodelObj});
```

Comment: If I pass model as a argument to compositeView it's working fine. I have one more doubt.If I observe my code,I written manually I mention model instance name for setting up the attribute value.Instead of that I tried `this.set({name:"updatedValue"})`.it's not working. Actually What I am trying also correct way,because single view might be have more models and collections.If it is right How can I pass more model instances.If you not understand(what I am trying) let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To do this though you need to pass the model in when creating the `backView` like so:

```
var backViewObj = new backView({ el:$("#sidebar"), model: myModel });
```

Marionette accomplishes this by overriding `delegateEvents` which `Backbone.View` calls in it's constructor and delegating your `modelEvents` object to the model:

```
Marionette.bindEntityEvents(this, this.model, Marionette.getOption(this, "modelEvents"));
```

Based on your comments above I think that you're unclear about the different types of views that Backbone.Marionette provides as you are asking how to pass more model instances.  I also was unclear when I began using Marionette.

---

**`Marionette.ItemView`** represents a single model.

**`Marionette.CollectionView`** represents a collection and renders a `Marionette.ItemView` for every model in the collection.  It does not have the ability to render a template.

**`Marionette.CompositeView`** represents both a model and a collection (leaf and branch in a tree structure).  This is for recursive data structures although you can use a CompositeView to render a template (like a table header, etc.) and use `itemViewContainer` to place the itemViews in a specific element.

If you want your CompositeView to be able to render multiple models you'll need to pass a collection of models into the CompositeView and not one single model: